# Added JSF Tomahawk Library Removes Space Between List Items

Tags: jsf-2, tomahawk

I added the JSF Tomahawk Library and as soon as I did, it caused the space between the first menu items in my menu to lose the space between them. But without Tomahawk, there is no issue.

Correct Format and Before Tomahawk was Added:

[image: Correct Format]

This is what is it looks like after tomahawk is added:

[image: Bug/Tomahawk error]

I dont know why this is happening, there is nothing different in the HTML or the code. Literally as soon as this gets added it happens. Has anyone had this problem before? And if so, how did you fix it?

I am running MyFace 2.0, Tomahawk 1.1.14. If there is any more information you would believe to be relevant, please let me know and I'll grab it.

Comment: "(...) there is nothing different in the HTML or the code" - have you heard about CSS?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explicitly say it but CSS hasn't changed either.